# Why my notification is being scheduled 5 hours earlier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I am making an app where I have to schedule local notifications for all the time stamps that is stored in my database when the app will be installed for the first time.

The notifications are being scheduled but when the alarm rings, I realize it is ringing at a time that is exactly 5 hours delayed than the current time. Imagine, I have 3 notifications to go off today- one at 2:11 pm, another at 3:18 pm and another at 8:15 pm. Now, imagine my current time is 7:11pm. I will have a notification go off. which is exactly 5 hours after my first timestamp. Then again it is go off at 8:18 pm.

The following is my code. Can anyone please help.

```
-(void) setLocalNotification {
    TimeCalculationLogic *timeManager = [[TimeCalculationLogic alloc]init];

    NSMutableArray *allTimeStamps = [timeManager getAllTimeStamps];
    NSDate *currentTime;

    for(beginningTime *time in allTimeStamps){

        NSDate *currentDate = [timeManager getDateFromString:time.activeDate];

        currentTime = [timeManager getDateTimestampFromString:time.first];
        [self getComponentToScheduleNotificationFromDate:currentDate andTime:currentTime];

        currentTime = [timeManager getDateTimestampFromString:time.second];
        [self getComponentToScheduleNotificationFromDate:currentDate andTime:currentTime];

        currentTime = [timeManager getDateTimestampFromString:time.third];
        [self getComponentToScheduleNotificationFromDate:currentDate andTime:currentTime];
   }
    NSArray *activeNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    // Add back the still relevant notifications
    for (UILocalNotification *notification in activeNotifications) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
    }
}

-(void)getComponentToScheduleNotificationFromDate:(NSDate*)date andTime:(NSDate*)timestamp{
    self.schedulerComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    NSCalendar *calender = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601];

    NSDateComponents *components;
    components = [calender components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:date];
    NSInteger day = [components day];
    NSInteger month = [components month];
    NSInteger year = [components year];

    [self.schedulerComponent setYear:year];
    [self.schedulerComponent setMonth:month];
    [self.schedulerComponent setDay:day];

    components = [calender components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:timestamp];

    NSInteger hour = [components hour];
    NSInteger minute = [components minute];
    NSInteger second = [components second];

    [self.schedulerComponent setHour:hour];
    [self.schedulerComponent setMinute:minute];
    [self.schedulerComponent setSecond:second];

    [self.schedulerComponent setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601];
    NSDate *setTime = [cal dateFromComponents:self.schedulerComponent];

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = setTime;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

    localNotif.alertBody = @"It's time Again!";
    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

    localNotif.soundName = @"ajan.caf";
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];

}
```

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with the code of notification, it is something related to timezone, may be it is taking UTC time and sending notification.

Comment: But I am setting system timezon

Comment: I think you'd want the local time zone instead, right? Either that or your timeManager needs to create dates with systemTimeZone as well, I think. Most likely the timeManager uses the local time zone when creating dates.

Comment: I will have to check that.